# Jquery Cycle2 goto slide

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery cycle2 nested slider for my project. On each slide I have image/trigger on which I need to click and go to last slide(4). I have it as follow:

```
$("#test").click (function(){
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 4);
});
```

This does not work, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you probably have figured it out but for someone that is stuck at this issue, all you need to do is to add a `return false;` at the end:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 4);
    return false;
});
```

Very very simple, isn't?  I strongly recommend you to read the Cycle's API at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#commands